# ihow to acees random items from an array and then put them in another array in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i have a problem i have an array which has ten items "one" to "ten"
i want to get randon items from this array and put them in a new array which can display the random items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// seed the random number generator    
srand([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);

// get random item
NSObject *randomItem = [yourArray objectAtIndex:rand() % [yourArray count]];

// insert item
[newMutableArray addObject:randomItem];
```